# Mongo insert only if total document count is less than N

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to insert a document into mongo only if the total count returned by my query is less than a certain threshold number N. Is this kind of query possible in mongodb or should I switch to relational databases where this can be handled with case and where constraints in the query.

I am looking for a solution where these kind of insertions would happen at high scale and concurrency, and still the insertion threshold should not get exceeded.

I could find this kind of solution in relational databases, also doing a POC with SP(Stored Procedures) to find if this can be handled.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using an aggregation pipeline. For example:

1. An example of your query (which can be how many steps you need)
2. `$count` all results documents and create one document
3. Keep the document only if the count is less than N
4. Replace with the doc you want to insert
5. Format it
6. Insert into the collection (if the condition is not met, nothing will be inserted)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {your query}},
  {$count: "count"},
  {$match: {count: {$lt: N}}},
  {$project: {doc: newDoc}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$doc"}},
  {$merge: {into: "collection"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u5CXNvLQGhy)